# passing array as parameter in sqlite Swift

Tags: swift, sqlite

I implemented Sqlite in my project by adding `#import <sqlite3.h>` in my `header.h` file and `libsqlite3.dylib`.

How can I pass an array as parameter to my query, here is what I thought:

```
var arrayId = [1,2] // array with interested Id 
var query:NSString = "Select id from Product where id IN \(arrayId)" // I want to select Products with id that are in the array
```

**Edit**:
Does it change if arrayId is `NSArray` ? Because I also need arrayId as NSArray.

then I proceed with open sqlite database, prepare query and so on.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since this post is a top ten search engine result for the same question, note that since 2016 there is a loadable table-valued function extension (not compiled into sqlite by default) called [carray()](https://sqlite.org/carray.html) that lets you bind an array as an inline table against which to join your query (instead of an 'IN' clause).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily combine the array into a string with join function.

```
var arrayId = [1,2] // array with interested Id
var inExpression = ",".join(map(arrayId) { "\($0)"})
// inExpression = "1,2"
var query = "Select id from Product where id IN (\(inExpression))"
```

Comment: Even NSArray can be used the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Update for Swift3:

```
var arrayId = [1,2] // array with interested Id
var inExpression = arrayId.flatMap{ String($0) }.joined(separator: ",")
// inExpression = "1,2"
var query = "SELECT id FROM Product WHERE id IN (\(inExpression))"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to accomplish two things: convert your array of `Int`s to `String`s and then implode the array into a string, by joining them with commas (as you would want to do with an `IN` SQL statement).

Here's a rudimentary function that does just that:

```
func implode(ints: [Int]) -> String {
    // Convert to Strings
    let strs = ints.map { String($0) }
    // Join Strings with commas
    return ",".join(strs)
}
```

And then in use:

```
"WHERE id IN (\(implode(arrayId)))"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use something like:

```
var arrayId = [1,2] // array with interested Id
var str = ",".join(arrayId.map { return "\($0)" })
var query = "SELECT id FROM Product WHERE id IN [\(str)]"
```

Comment: in this way my query is `SELECT id FROM Product WHERE id IN [1,2]`, I execute this on SQLite Manager, there is an error: `no such table: 1,2`

Comment: Try it with parenthesis around the `\(str)` instead of brackets.  I was guessing at the actual SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Using Swift's own string interpolation to create SQL statements can be risky (as with any language). The sqlite3 library provides parameter binding for this purpose:

```
if (statement.prepare("SELECT name FROM products WHERE id = ?") != .Ok) {
    // Deal with error here
}

// Bind the question mark to your value
statement.bindInt(1, value: 8766)

if (statement.step() == .Row) {
    let name = statement.getStringAt(1)
    // ...do something with your data from the statement
}

// Done.
statement.finalizeStatement()
```

EDIT:

For the comment below, you need () brackets, not []:

```
select id, body from test where id in (1,2);
```

not

```
select id, body from test where id in [1,2];
```

Comment: Your comment is valid, but doesn't really answer the question of how to pass in an Array of Int's as an IN parameter.

Comment: As @David said, it doesn't answer the question. Thank you anyway.